# Resource Router - no routes will work

Tags: resource-router

I've installed Resource Router and set up a few basic routes, but they don't seem to be working.  No routes will work at all, is there something else I need to do to "activate" the plugin?

Edit to add code:

We're using the Focus Labs multi environment config, so in my config.php I've got:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config/config.master.php';
```

I've then called Resource Router in config.master.php with:

```
// Resource Router
 $env_config['resource_router'] = require 'routes.php';
```

And in my routes.php, I've set up a simple route:

```
<?php 
return [ 
'careers/:any' => 'careers/article',
];
```

I am getting as far as the routes.php file as I can echo something out from it, but just can't get the routes to work.

Comment: If it's showing "installed" in add-ons that should be it. Post your resource router code?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I've updated the comment above with code.

Comment: Have you tried moving rr code to config.php in system folder and bypassing master config for testing? $config['resource_router'] = array(
   'careers/:any' => 'careers/article',
);

Comment: Hi, I did try that before I posted the questions, but it didn't work at the time.  I just tried it again, and it's decided to work this time.  I guess we'll just have to leave the master config set up out for now.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the master config set up isn't working, but taking it out and moving the routers to the standard config file is working correctly

Comment: Glad you have it working. One other thought: if your php version is less than 5.4 your example 'short' syntax [] wouldn't work, and you'd need to use array(). Not sure if that applies to your install though... http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php